# How can I perform the SQL query against different database systems?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle

I have a question about how to perform database queries against different database systems?

For example, I have a following SQL query string:

```
SELECT A.F1, A.F2, B.F3, B.F4 
FROM TableA A, TableB B 
WHERE A.ID=B.ID AND B.ID=xyz
```

Is there any solution that I can perform the above query when:

- TableA is from an Oracle database, TableB is also from an Oracle database from another instance
- TableA is from a SQL Server database, TableB is from an Oracle database
- TableA is from an Oracle database, TableB is from a SQL Server database
- TableA is from a SQL Server database, TableB is also from a SQL Server database from another SQL Server instance

I know that for situation #1 I can use the ORACLE DATABASE LINK feature (also maybe #3). But is there any common solution which can address all of the scenarios above? For instance, maybe there is another scenario that I want to join two tables from MySQL and SQL Server databases.

For coding I am using C#/.NET, any recommendation is welcome, including joining the data in the code.

Thanks!

Comment: Do some research on `sp_addlinkedserver`.

Answer (score 0):

This is known as a federated query

You can use SQL Servers federation ability (linked servers) and run the query in SQL Server. You can use Oracles federation ability (Oracle heterogeneous services) and run the query in Oracle.

Either way you need to pick a database server, make the other (foreign) database known to that server then execute the query on the server.

Keep in mind you cannot expect good performance from this as in most cases the executing server is loading all the source records locally and joining locally.

Otherwise you need to write your own 'federation' ability in your app. This is non trivial, i.e. data types don't match exactly between vendors so you need to build some smarts. Also if you are joining particularly large tables you'd better make sure your algorithm is optimised or you'll run our of memory. Further to this, federated query ability in existing products (SQL, Oracle, Cognos etc.) is the result of very large companies doing a lot of development.

Can you tell us how many records you expect to join, and are the various source database servers mostly fixed or is this for an ad hoc query tool?

Comment: Hello, ElectricLIama, thank you for your answer. Actually this is for a query tool we built. The requirement is that we need to perform queries (joins) from different database instances, from different database types. For example, we may have a "TableCollection", with a "Base Table" defined in it, and all other child tables will be defined under this "Base Table" by joining. The number of records could vary from hundreds to millions of records.

Comment: If you do some research on 'federated queries' or 'heterogenous joins' you'll see what the large vendors have done about this. If there is a considerable difference in size between the tables then it makes sense to perform the join on the server with the biggest table. But basically this is a non trivial task.

Comment: I suggest this will be more reliable but less efficient if you do this in the app. If you try to build a custom implementation that builds linked servers (SQL) or DB links (Oracle) on the fly you are doomed to failure.

Comment: You'll need to expland on your Base Table/Child table explanation further. Is this meant to be portable to be sold externally? Why would someone want to define tables in different databases? Is it some kind of consolidation tool? I gurarantee someone has already thought of it and is selling it!

Comment: Yes, actually I am also confused about such strange requirement from business. However this is still the thing that we need to implement in the project. Another choice might be that, we define a Stored Procedure on database B, accepting a list of IDs and create a temp table with only 1 column containing all these IDs. After querying database A, app will call this SP on DB 2 to create a temp table with all IDs returned by A, then make a JOIN query with this temp table in DB 2. But I am not sure if this approach would work. Seems still a lot of things to do.

Comment: Do you own these databases? If it's a third part vendor database then they won't like/allow you to create the required objects. Can you clarify this point - do you own the databases or not? It really sounds like business is trying to solve a problem without any technical guidance and coming up with a totally crazy solution. You should really try and understand the root problem rather than doing what you're asking, it sounds like they don't understand something fundamental.